# Chunked file upload with angular-js and jquery-file-uplad, nginx and rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, nginx, jquery-file-upload

I am trying to do chunked file upload with angular-js and jquery-file-uplad (form github/blueimp). Backend is rails application running on nginx.

Jquery file upload is sending only first chunk and then stops on receiving 201 from nginx server.

Document [here](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Uploading-to-nginx-using-the-nginx-upload-module) specifies that nginx should return 201 Created and not 200.
Can't seem to figure out what is wrong here.

Following are relevant code sections

## JS

```
 (function () {
    'use strict';
        var url = 'jquploadhandle';

    blueshiftApp.config([
            '$httpProvider', 'fileUploadProvider',
            function ($httpProvider, fileUploadProvider) {
                delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
                fileUploadProvider.defaults.redirect = window.location.href.replace(
                    /\/[^\/]*$/,
                    '/cors/result.html?%s'
                );
            }
        ])

        .controller('DemoFileUploadController', [
            '$scope', '$http', '$filter', '$window',
            function ($scope, $http) {
                $scope.options = {
                    url: url,
                    dataTtype: 'text',
                    multipart: false,
                    maxChunkSize: 4000000, //Bytes
                    sequentialUploads: true,
                };

                $scope.loadingFiles = false;
                $('#fileupload').bind('fileuploadadd', function(e, data){
                    if (data.headers === undefined) {
                        data.headers = {};
                    }
                    data.headers['Session-Id'] = "0000000277"
                   });
            }
        ])

        .controller('FileDestroyController', [
            '$scope', '$http',
            function ($scope, $http) {
                var file = $scope.file,
                    state;
                if (file.url) {
                    file.$state = function () {
                        return state;
                    };
                    file.$destroy = function () {
                        state = 'pending';
                        return $http({
                            url: file.deleteUrl,
                            method: file.deleteType
                        }).then(
                            function () {
                                state = 'resolved';
                                $scope.clear(file);
                            },
                            function () {
                                state = 'rejected';
                            }
                        );
                    };
                } else if (!file.$cancel && !file._index) {
                    file.$cancel = function () {
                        $scope.clear(file);
                    };
                }
            }
        ]);
    }());
```

## HTML Markup

```
 <form id="fileupload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-ng-controller="DemoFileUploadController" data-file-upload="options" data-ng-class="{'fileupload-processing': processing() || loadingFiles}">
<!-- Redirect browsers with JavaScript disabled to the origin page -->
<!-- The fileupload-buttonbar contains buttons to add/delete files and start/cancel the upload -->
<!-- The fileinput-button span is used to style the file input field as button -->
<div class="form-group col-md-offset-4">
  <label class="form-inline control-label col-md-3">
    Upload File
    <span class="required">* </span>
  </label>
  <input type="file" name="file" accept="text/csv, application/json" ng-required="true" ng-disabled="disabled">
  <label> Download Sample 
    <a href='/crm_feeds.csv'> CSV <i class='fa fa-share-square-o'></i> </a>
  </label>
  <p ng-show="invalid_file" class="help-block">CRM data file is required.</p>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="form-inline col-md-5" > 
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default cancel" data-ng-click="cancel()">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i>
      <span>Cancel</span>
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="form-inline btn btn-primary start" data-ng-click="submit()">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i>
      <span>Validate</span>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <!-- The global file processing state -->
  <span class="fileupload-process"></span>
</div>
<!-- The global progress state -->
<div class="col-lg-5 fade" data-ng-class="{in: active()}" style="margin-top:7px">
  <!-- The global progress bar -->
  <div class="progress progress-striped active" data-file-upload-progress="progress()"><div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" data-ng-style="{width: num + '%'}"></div></div>
  <!-- The extended global progress state -->
  <div class="progress-extended">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

## Nginx Config

```
user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  logs/error.log;
error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
worker_connections  20;
}


http {
include       mime.types;
default_type  application/octet-stream;
upstream localapp {
  server 127.0.0.1:3000;
}

#access_log  logs/access.log  main;

sendfile        on;
#tcp_nopush     on;

#keepalive_timeout  0;
keepalive_timeout  65;

#gzip  on;

server {
    client_max_body_size 4G;
    client_body_buffer_size 1024k;
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost:3000;


    #charset koi8-r;

    #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;
    location /jquploadhandle {
      upload_max_file_size 0;
      upload_pass /post_jquploadhandle.json;
      upload_store /store;
      upload_state_store /store/states;
      upload_store_access user:rw group:rw all:r;
      upload_resumable on;

      upload_set_form_field file[name] "$upload_file_name";
      upload_set_form_field file[content_type] "$upload_content_type";
      upload_set_form_field file[filepath] "$upload_tmp_path";

      upload_pass_form_field "^theme_id$|^blog_id$|^authenticity_token$|^format$";
      upload_cleanup 400 404 499 500-505;
    }

    location / {
        root   html;
        index  index.html index.htm @app;
        proxy_pass  http://localapp;  
    }

    location @upload {
      proxy_pass  http://localapp;
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }
}
}
```